# Chat waiting time feedback

Tags: user-expectation, user-centered-design, feedback, response-time, chat

We have a Live Chat services but the problem is we don't have enough number of agents to answer all the inquiries of all customers. So customers really need to wait especially during peak hours.

Our initial solution is to show the Queue number and the estimated waiting time but at the moment, we can't implement it due to technical limitations.

Do you guys have any suggestion on how we can improve our Live Chat experience for customers waiting? What do you think is the proper message to tell to the customers that they need to wait in a way that they will understand the situation and they will not be frustrated. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to switch to a channel where asynchronous communication is common (e.g. WhatsApp)?

Comment: How about letting your users play a mini-game or solve a trivia puzzle while they are waiting for an agent to be assigned?

Answer (score 2):

The only source of frustration you can control with this approach is uncertainty around the wait time. You don't need a technical solution to help your customers manage this uncertainty. Manually calculate the average wait time during peak hours and provide this in your message, for example, "Between 8-10 am you may have to wait up to 15 minutes for an agent." You can calculate this figure using past data on agent response times.

Comment: Thanks Andre! But our problem is, we can't compute the average waiting time at the moment. So we are limited to just informing them about waiting but not giving the details about how long they should wait etc.

Comment: @king321 I think Andre was suggesting that you look at past performance and set up static messages to display to your users at the appropriate times (e.g. how long does it usually take to speak to an agent at this time of day). This estimation doesn't have to be dynamic, or update as time passes, but it would help a user who, for example, is connecting during their lunch break that the wait could be 45 minutes, so they should instead try at a later time. Are you saying that you don't track how long your users have waited to reach an agent?

Comment: @maxathousand yeah that's what I meant. I'll update the answer to make it clearer.